# Java Multithreaded I/0 and communication problem

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, io

I am using java to create an application for network management. In this application I establish communication with network devices using SNMP4j library (for the snmp protocol). So, Im supposed to scan certain values of the network devices using this protocol and put the result into a file for caching. Up in some point I decided to make my application multi-threaded and assign a device to a thread.  I created a class that implements the runnable interface and then scans for the values that I want for each device.

When i run this class alone it, works fine. but when I put multiple threads at the same time the output mess up, it prints additional or out of order output into the files. Now, i wonder if this problem is due to the I/O or due to the communication.

Here I'll put some of the code so that you can see what im doing and help me figure what's wrong.

```
public class DeviceScanner implements Runnable{
private final SNMPCommunicator comm;
private OutputStreamWriter out;

public DeviceScanner(String ip, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
        this.device=ip;
        this.comm = new SNMPV1Communicator(device);

        oids=MIB2.ifTableHeaders;
        out = new OutputStreamWriter(output);

    }

@Override
    public void run(){
//Here I use the communicator to request for desired data goes something like ...
                String read=""
        for (int j=0; j&lt;num; j++){

                read= comm.snmpGetNext(oids);
                out.write(read);
                this.updateHeaders(read);

            }
            out.flush();
//...
   }

}
```

some of the expected ooutput would be something like:

1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = SmartSTACK ELS100-S24TX2M

1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0 = 1.3.6.1.4.1.52.3.9.1.10.7

1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = 26 days, 22:35:02.31

1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0 = admin

1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = els

1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0 = Computer Room

but instead i get something like (varies):

1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = SmartSTACK ELS100-S24TX2M

1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0 = 1.3.6.1.4.1.52.3.9.1.10.7

1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0 = admin

1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = els

1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = 26 days, 22:35:02.31

1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0 = Computer Room

1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = SmartSTACK ELS100-S24TX2M

1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0 = 1.3.6.1.4.1.52.3.9.1.10.7

*Currently I have one file per device scanner desired.
i get them from a list of ip , it looks like this. Im also using a little threadpool to keep a limited number of threads at the same time .

```
for (String s: ips){
            output= new FileOutputStream(new File(path+s));
            threadpool.add(new DeviceScanner(s, output));
        }
```

Comment: it helps most if you post a *complete but minimal* (compilable but only what is needed to show the problem) example; that said, you probably want to look into "synchronized" methods or statements.

Comment: I'd also recommend studying up on output stream buffering and `flush()`

Comment: The output is a huge file that probably I shouldnt post online (contains private network data) but as I mentioned, it repeats some output as well as putting it in random order.

Comment: @Jim I was wondering about that, since I am putting lots of data before flushing, does it has a limit? is there a better way to output?

Comment: Without seeing at least a *sample* of how the output is different from what you expect, it's awfully hard to make concrete suggestions.

Comment: What is `MIB2.ifTableHeaders;` ? Google serves up nothing.

Comment: Those are some String values that ill be requesting to the device

Comment: As far as I can see, in your "wrong" output, the only thing that's wrong is that 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 appears later than you're expecting.  ....1.1.0 and ....1.2.0 at the end are, I presume, the following reply.

I'm not familiar with SNMP4j, so I don't know if it makes any guarantees about ordering - maybe it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect SNMPV1Communicator(device) is not thread-safe. As I can see it's not a part of SNMP4j library.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a wild guess at what's going on here, try putting everything inside a `synchronized()` block, like this:

```
 synchronized (DeviceScanner.class)
 {
        for (int j=0; j&lt;num; j++){
            read= comm.snmpGetNext(oids);
            out.write(read);
            this.updateHeaders(read);

        }
        out.flush();
 }
```

If this works, my guess is right and the reason for the problems you're seeing is that you have many `OutputStreamWriter`s (one on each thread), all writing to a single `OutputStream`.  Each `OutputStreamWriter` has its own buffer.  When this buffer is full, it passes the data to the `OutputStream`.  It's essentially random when each each `OutputStreamWriter`'s buffer is full - it might well be in the middle of a line.

The synchronized block above means that only one thread at a time can be writing to that thread's `OutputStreamWriter`.  The `flush()` at the end means that before leaving the synchronized block, the `OutputStreamWriter`'s buffer should have been flushed to the underlying `OutputStream`.

Note that synchronizing in this way on the class object isn't what I'd consider best practice.  You should probably be looking at using a single instance of some other kind of stream class - or something like a `LinkedBlockingQueue`, with all of the SNMP threads passing their data over to a single file-writing thread.  I've added the synchronized as above because it was the only thing available to synchronize on within your pasted example code.

Comment: This pretty much makes using threads moot because you're serializing all operations.

Comment: Brian - if I understand questioner's code correctly, the change above would only serialise the file-writing, not the SNMP operations.  (Not that I think this is going to be the world's best design, but I'm answering the question, not giving a class on design...)

Comment: I was just figuring `read= comm.snmpGetNext(oids)` was doing the read. If not, then yeah. Bit there's still no guarantee in regard to thread scheduling if he thinks he'll get those outputs in a specific order.

Comment: Each Device scanner is currently assigned to a different OutputStream, because I have a file for each device. I just tried it and still doesn't work.

Comment: I think you're going to need to formally define "doesn't work" and post some more code ... we're really all just making educated guesses at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You've got multiple threads all using buffered output, and to the same file.

There's no guarantees as to when those threads will be scheduled to run ... the output will be fairly random ordered, dictated by the thread scheduling.

Comment: Im sorry Brian, I forgot to mention that for now, im using a file per device, that's why i was expecting the data in certain order